# Can't scroll using Scroll View

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I press play, I can't move the scrollbar or the scroll view. The scrollbar also resets for some reason...

I was trying to make a questionnaire but it just doesn't work. And yes, I have set [the viewport and the scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWFm7.png), and [the react transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvd1T.png).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This question isn't really related to code and would be better suited for another place like the Unity forums.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add vetrical or horizontal layout group to content gameobject under scrollview>viewport>content. also you have to add content size fitter and set it to preferred size for vertical or horizontal. then your scrollview will work.